# BING wallpaper on Lock screen

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lock-screen, nokia-lumia-1320, bing, wallpaper

I have Lumia 1320. I have set the BING as the Background property for Lock Screen wallpapers. But the wallpaper are not changing, also there is no option for changing the BING wallpaper to next wallpaper.

Also my phone is connected to internet, in case it need internet access.

So my question is how can the BING wallpaper on lock screen will change oftenly.

Answer (score 1):

First, set a simple picture as background in order to stop using Bing.
Then, restart your phone.
Now, set Bing wallpapers another time. It should works.

Comment: BING wallpapers are working but it takes too much time to change to the next BING wallpaper. so can we set or manually change the current BING wallpaper to next BING wallpaper ?

Comment: @AkshayChawla no, you can't make it change manually

Comment: Now its been 2-3 days that i am using that BING wallpaper setting, and i guess it is changing the wallpaper everyday around noon time.